# How to find all vertices that have no incoming edges in TinkerPop 3?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

How would write a traversal in use Gremlin TinkerPop 3 to find all vertices that have no incoming edges?

As a follow up I also need to find a vertices that have no outgoing edges as well.

Answer (score 10):

This is simpler than the below version

```
g.V().not(inE())
g.V().not(outE())
```

Keeping my original answer for reference

```
g.V().where(inE().count().is(eq(0)))
```

For 0 outgoing edges

```
g.V().where(outE().count().is(eq(0)))
```

Comment: This is correct, but can be simplified: `g.V().not(inE())`

Comment: @DanielKuppitz Like! This is definitely simpler. I'll change my answer to use yours.